# Cross-checking file lines against list of strings in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I have a file **A** that contains 3M lines, and I have an array **arr** of 500k items of two columns (**col1**, **col2**), I need to check which lines in file **A** have some information that matches **col1** in **arr** and form a string of the next lines and concatenate **col2** to the end of the string.

This is a sample I created to show the logic of my code:

```
def myfun(file, arr):

arr = quicksort(arr) # quick sort custom implementation
                     # arr will have duplicate values

with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('something'):

            lineparts = line.split() #line will be space seperated columns
                                     #we need second column

            idx = binary_search(arr, lineparts[1]) #index of col2 value in arr if found
                                                   # -1 if not found

            if idx != -1:           #if found store col2 value for later use
                temp_var = arr[idx][1]
                del arr[idx]        # delete arr entry as it's not needed anymore
            else:
                #do something
                temp_var = '0'

            #
            #   do concatenation of strings in lines as needed
            #   after finishing preparing the needed string
            #   write it to a new file
            #
```

This code works fine, but it is time consuming.
Is there a better approach for such tasks? *"Assume **quicksort** and **binary_search** are implemented in the most suitable way".*

Comment: Why not just store the col1->col2 mapping in a dict?  No need to binary_search, nor deleting "used" mappings.  Just run through the lines once and check each line against the dict.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I can't do that, because the values aren't unique values, and the same value might have different mapping if it appear in two different locations. It's a text feature generation problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears something has slipped past my eyes, the answer was very obvious to my problem.

*Deleting the array entry causes any programming language to allocate another array, copy the original one without the element I'm deleting*, hence, so much running time.

**Note**: it should be a normal array with random access through indices, just for clarification.

after I deleted the line `del arr[idx]`, the running time went down from 72 seconds to 6 seconds.

Still, if there's a better approach, please do leave an answer!